# Why isn't oncopy working with React but working with normal JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to react js, can seem to understand why oncopy event is not working as intended.

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>

<h1 oncopy="alert('copy1');">
I love react
</h1>
```

JS

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div oncopy="alert('copy2');">I hate react</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/ejdcx517/

Answer (score 0):

At first event props in react use capitalized letters (camel case). Second, you need to pass a function as an event handler in jsx. When you use `""` it is considered to be string value. You need to pass function between curly braces `{}`:

```
onCopy={() => alert('copy2')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event with `camel case` and execute the statements with ES6 style arrow functions like

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div onCopy={()=> alert('copy2')}>I hate react</div>;
  }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ejdcx517/1/)**